# Recursion: look like same function but print out different flow of execution

Tags: python, variables, recursion, execution, factorial

I tried to print out flow of execution of factorial recursion function.

```
def factorial(n):
    space=' '*(4*n)
    print(space,'factorial ',n)
    if n==0:
        print(space,'returning 1')
        return 1
    else:
        recurse=factorial(n-1)
        result=n*recurse
        print(space,'returning ', result)
        return n*recurse
```

With factorial(2) result will be correct:

```
        factorial 2
    factorial 1
factorial 0
returning 1
    returning 1
        returning 2
2
```

But when I don't use variable recurse=factorial(n-1):

```
def factorial(n):
    space=' '*(4*n)
    print(space,'factorial ',n)
    if n==0:
        print(space,'returning 1')
        return 1
    else:
        result=n*factorial(n-1)
        print(space,'returning ', result)
        return n*factorial(n-1)
```

then with factorial(2) it printed out different flow:

```
             factorial  2
     factorial  1
 factorial  0
 returning 1
     returning  1
 factorial  0
 returning 1
         returning  2
     factorial  1
 factorial  0
 returning 1
     returning  1
 factorial  0
 returning 1
2
```

My question is: why was there different flow of executions [with and without variable recurse=factorial(n-1)]?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're calling the function twice, once on result and once on return

Comment: My question is: why was there different flow of executions [with and without variable recurse=factorial(n-1)]?

Comment: You should be returning `result` in the second version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to below extra function call in your code

```
def factorial(n):
    space=' '*(4*n)
    print(space,'factorial ',n)
    if n==0:
        print(space,'returning 1')
        return 1
    else:
        result=n*factorial(n-1)
        print(space,'returning ', result)
        return n*factorial(n-1)   # factorial(n-1) is called second time so that this function is executed once again
```

You could do as below for similar execution

```
def factorial(n):
    space=' '*(4*n)
    print(space,'factorial ',n)
    if n==0:
        print(space,'returning 1')
        return 1
    else:
        result=n*factorial(n-1)
        print(space,'returning ', result)
        return result
```